# Change Default Home User

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I received a laptop with Mac OSX 10.8.4 installed that doesn't show a user named "usera" in system preferences --> user&groups list of users.  I've added a new user there "userb".  Whenever I open up a Terminal window, the usera shows as the default home directory.  How do I change the default home directory to userb?

Comment: Login in userb account

Comment: @ParagBafna I am logged in as userb but the terminal still show usera

Answer (score 0):

Use su -- substitute user identity

```
$ su - userb
Password:
```

Comment: that didn't work here is the output Last login: Fri Aug 16 10:28:18 on ttys000
Brads-MacBook-Pro:~ usera$ su - userb
Password:
su: Sorry
Brads-MacBook-Pro:~ usera$

Comment: That give me "sudo: unknown user: userb" even though userb has a directory in /Users and shows up in preferences, users and groups list.